# FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) with Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have read through the documnentation but I just want to double check I am not missing something: Is it true that we cannot yet use FCM with Windows Phone?

RTFM I know

Comment: There is currently no WP client for FCM.

Comment: Where can I find it, pls?

Comment: @UilqueMessias docs are here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/