# Is there a way to send free unlimited push notifications via FCM?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, pushbots

Presently I am using Pushbots to send notification to all my Android subscribers. However, to send unlimited messages I have to pay 500 USD/month.

My app is build in Cordova. Please let me know if there is another way to do the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how many subscribers do you have? how often do you want to send push notifications?

Comment: FCM [is free](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

Comment: Currently approx. 37k, so by sending couple of messages for each transaction/promotion adds to cost. Yes, I am looking into FCM. I just found out Firebase has a cordova plugin. Do you know whether it works across platforms such as iOS and windows mobile ? Anyways thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (FCM), previous version known as Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), is completely free of charge. See [Firebase Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/):

> Included Free
>
> Analytics, App Indexing, Authentication, **Cloud Messaging**, Crash Reporting, Dynamic Links, Invites, Notifications & Remote Config

A quick Google search shows that there is an available [FCM Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm). Then you should go ahead and make use of [Topic Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging). From the plugin link:

> **Subscribe to topic**
>
> ```
> //FCMPlugin.subscribeToTopic( topic, successCallback(msg), errorCallback(err) );
> //All devices are subscribed automatically to 'all' and 'ios' or 'android' topic respectively.
> //Must match the following regular expression: "[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]{1,900}".
> FCMPlugin.subscribeToTopic('topicExample');
> ```

The idea is quite simple. Simply have **all** your users subscribed to a topic, then send a message towards that topic, and it should be delivered to all of them.

Comment: Thanks sir! Do you know whether it works across platforms such as iOS and windows mobile ?

Comment: @SouravBiswas It works for [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client). For Windows Phone, I don't think so. See the comment by Arthur Thompson in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38150309/4625829).