# FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) in Windows Mobile App (Cordova)?

Tags: cordova, firebase, windows-mobile, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created mobile App with Cordova 5.0 in Android and iOS. Now, I want to develop the same App in Windows Platform. I am able to use other plug-ins as they provide Windows platform support too. [Here](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) is a plug-in I used for FCM.

This plugin does not provide Windows support, so I am planning to go with Windows native programming.

Does FCM provide Native Windows support?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no Windows Phones client for FCM.

Comment: A similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38150309/4625829) was asked before. See comments section, comment by @ArthurThompson.

Comment: Can't we use Web(JavaScript) platform provided by FCM? as cordova also using javaScript.

Comment: @ketanpatel It supports a Web platform, which I think is (probably) different from Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is OneSignal 
OneSignal plugin works with iOS, ANDROID and WINDOWS PHONE 8.1.
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk