# Using Firebase Notifications cross platform

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm searching for a solution for push notifications. For me Firebase is really attractive. 
My question now is can I use it cross platform?
I think Firebase is a google service and thus will require the Google PlayServices, right? How can I consume Firebase Cloud Messages / Notificataion in my iOS App or Windows Store app. 
I have a own backend where all the auth stuff and data is, but because I want to save time I don't want to implement a own solution
Is this possible or not? Or can you recommend me any other framework/service?

Comment: Just check out the firebase docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

In short: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. FCM routes all of your iOS notifications to APNs, so by the time these notifications reach your iOS device, they look just like any other iOS notification.

If you want all the nitty-gritty details, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1SDBIViRtE) might help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Todd's answer

> *I think Firebase is a google service and thus will require the Google PlayServices, right?*

Yup. For Android devices.

> *How can I consume Firebase Cloud Messages / Notificataion in my iOS App or Windows Store app.*

Like Todd said, FCM forwards the messages for iOS devices to APNs. [There is currently no Windows Phones client for FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42220339/4625829).

> *I have a own backend where all the auth stuff and data is, but because I want to save time I don't want to implement a own solution*

To use FCM effectively accross different platforms, specially between Android and iOS, it is important to note that the behavior of [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) are different to both.

---

**Update**: A recent feature was added for FCM that gives an option to provide specific params for supported specific platforms, called [Platform Overrides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#customizing_a_message_across_platforms).

Comment: how about a windows app and not a windows phone app. Because w phone it not relevant.

Comment: Hi Simon. The "*No Windows Phone support*" also applies for a *Windows app*. There is currently no SDK that you could use to enable your app to receive FCM messages.